# Why my WinForm app not work in release mode?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem with my WinForm app. Debug mode works fine, but when I try to run my application into release mode I have an error:

System.BadImageFormatException
HResult=0x8007000B
Message = Unable to create file or assembly key 'SystemData.SQLite, Version = 1.0.76.0, Culture = neutral, PublicToken = db937bc2d44139' or one of its versions. An attempt was made for a program in an invalid format.

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, the values of Platform target and Prefer 32-bit matter.  Note the combobox at the top, labeled Configuration, it lets you flip between Debug and Release.  Make the Release values the same as the Debug values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio my first guess would be a x86/x64 mismatch between debug and release builds.

Are you using Nuget to get SQLLite?